# Paypal Live Site Testing

Tags: testing, paypal, magento-1.7, paypal-sandbox

I just wanted to ask among the gurus here if anyone has ever attempted to test a complete transaction from start to end on an ecommerce site using paypal or any other epayment gateway.

Please guys, I would appreciate any thoughts and comments. As it is a live site, I cant use the sandbox as that will negatively impact sales. However my firm is a startup and so can't afford the complete transaction and refund process that was suggested [here]:[Accepting dummy credit cards on a live site with ActiveMerchant & PayPal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999521/accepting-dummy-credit-cards-on-a-live-site-with-activemerchant-paypal).

Please help!

Comment: Either test it in [PayPal's sandbox](https://developer.paypal.com/), or use two accounts with Micro-payments of $0.05, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a similar problem during startup and still use this process in the live site. We have specific "test" products that we purchase using a live credit card, then monitor the transactions: purchase, decline purchase, subscription (recurring billing), cancel, refund, etc.

Our test product is priced very low (5 cents). For subscriptions, the billing interval is 1 day, for a maximum of 3 intervals (with a free trial period of 1 day). This allows me to run a full test/validation, including recurring billing, in the live environment in less than a week.

We refund all charges following the test, which puts the money back on the credit card (or back in the PayPal account). Because of the refunding, our sales impact is zero (offsetting sale and refund). It does cost us a small non-refundable PayPal fee for each transaction, but that amounts to $1 or less.

These "test" products are not exposed to normal users. Also, we manually verify any "test" sales to make sure they are part of our internal testing.

"Sandbox" testing is the way to go during development, but a periodic test in the live environment is necessary to be verify that nothing is amiss.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I thought. Although I had never considered the test products approach, will give that a try and should be better than the refund and paypal pay cycle, that's for sure!

Answer (score 1):

Previously I tested by buying low cost items from myself - that way you're only paying commission and you're getting most of the moneyback.

Admittedly you need 2 Paypal accounts, but that shouldn't be a problem, and you should only have to 'kick the tyres' in the live environment because all your testing will have been done in the dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a real credit card, then give yourself a refund? The commision fee is returned in that case.

Answer (score 0):

All the time that I want to test our live sites we use a real credit card.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @MageWH, I saw a lot of testing uses that, I was hoping to get a different solution though, one that does not involve using a real  paypal account or credit card as the refund is not FOC.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you can't use the sandbox..??  How would using it negatively impact your sales?  It's all fake.

Just setup your own sandbox.yourdomain.com version of your site and use that as your test server.  Configure it to use PayPal's sandbox with sandbox API credentials, etc.  This will allow you to go all the way through an order process and test everything from the UI stuff to payment processing, API requests/response processing, IPN, etc.

When everything is working you sync it up with your live server, which is hitting the live PayPal server, of course.

Again, I don't see how that would impact you in any way other than being a successful testing solution..??

Comment: This will negatively impact the site because the testing is a daily process that must be carried out on all live sites. We have the staged version, which has been tested, however it's a QC measure to also test the entire customer purchase process on each website(we have five) that is live on a daily basis to ensure all payment gateways and processes are working as they should. Company Policy.

Comment: I'm still not following.  Updating and testing on test servers is a very common practice.  I do it every day on numerous sites I manage.  It doesn't negatively effect any of them.  The test servers are separate from the live server so anything I'm doing there has nothing to do with the live server.  Once it's working on the sandbox I simply upload live and I know it'll work there, too.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is my tests are to be conducted on the live servers. QC type of thing as the devs before me built a super buggy site.

Comment: If your test server mirrors the live server, though, it's the same code in both places...no..??

Comment: Yeah. But they do require the testing be done on the actual live site.

Comment: Ok, well maybe just set a URL parameter flag to enable the sandbox on the live site only when you want to so that you can run through full tests on that exact subdomain..??